# How to upload file from my local storage into S3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

Looking at some samples how Laravel work with AWS S3 survice I see examples of code like :

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 's3');
```

But when I try to upload  file from my local storage :

```
   $adImageDestDirectory = '/public/' .  ‘subdirectory_path’;

  $path = Storage::get($adImageDestDirectory . $adImageItem->image)->store('images', 's3');
```

I got error:

```
Call to a member function store() on string
```

Which is valid way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to upload files from local storage to aws S3 bucket then you need to copy files from local: use function `file_get_contents()`

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('filename.jpg', file_get_contents($adImageDestDirectory );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to store the file to s3

```
$file = $request->file('attachment');
$fileName = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
$filePath = 'uploads/' . $fileName;
Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file), 'public');
$urlPath = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filePath);
```